# 2D Jumping Animation stuck on loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

I have added the jumping animation to my player. When my player jumps, the animation plays. However when the player lands, the jump animation becomes stuck. When I check the animator tab, the jump animation is just being played on a loop.

This is the Code for the Jumping stuff - Animation/actual movement:

```
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            animator.SetBool("isGrounded", true);
            jump = false;
        }

        Flip();
    }
```

This should check whether the player is grounded or not:

```
    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }
```

Comment: Your code to set isjumping will only be called when you are grounded AND just released the jump button. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This statement does not what you think it does

```
if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && IsGrounded())
```

`GetButtonUp` returns true the first frame the button is released (see [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonUp.html)).
But it will return `false` again if the button has been released. This is not made that clear in the docs. Or to put it in other words: `GetButtonUp` returns `true` in that frame where the button has been released but in the frame before it was still pressed.

You could just detect the moment the player lands to switch animations:

```
if (jump && IsGrounded()) {  // player just landed
     animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
     animator.SetBool("isGrounded", true);
     jump = false;
}
```